# How to left align enumerate labels at the left margin?

Tags: align, enumerate, enumitem

I'd like to align the numbering to the left margin, i.e. with the non-indented normal paragraph text, rather than having it go over the margin.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=15pt,labelindent=15pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}

\begin{document}
\noindent Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

This gets closer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt} % Default is 15pt.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=15pt,labelindent=15pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=15pt, align=left}

\begin{document}
Some text\\
\noindent Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But unfortunately, the indentation of text in items is greater than 15pt, as can be seen by comparing it to the indented normal text.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `wide=` option: it automatically sets `align=left` and the value of `labelindent`

```
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, widest=99,leftmargin=\parindent, labelsep=*}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it not only align the number to the left but also the text after label when it goes over more than one line. This is not desired.

Comment: You have to add `leftmargin=15pt` (or `leftmargin=*` if you want the default value). Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Now, the second line in 1 looks like it starts more to the right than the first. Also the text for the 10 does not left align with the text of the other items anymore.

Comment: It seems `\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=15pt, align=left}` gets closer. But then the text of the items starts more to the right than 15pt...

Comment: I have added an edit to the question that shows the problem.

Comment: @Daniel: The value you chose for leftmargin is too small. Better use `leftmargin=*`. Please see the updated code.

Comment: I can increase the margin if needed. However, the updated answer puts the item text more to the right than the normal, indented text. `\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=15pt, labelsep=0pt, align=left}` seems to work, but I am not sure whether it has any bad side effects.

Comment: The trick is to choose `labelsep=*`. See last version.

Answer (score 9):

Here it is: note, however, that `labelsep` is inherited by the nested lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=\parindent,align=left,labelwidth=\parindent,labelsep=0pt]
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\item Some more text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That looks right. What do you mean by "labelsep is inherited by the nested lists"?

Comment: @Daniel If you have an `enumerate` or `itemize` nested inside that `enumerate`, it will inherit the value for `\labelsep`.

Comment: I see. I guess I could get around it by setting it for a specific enumerate level.

Comment: This worked best for me when I put 'labelsep=*' as suggested in the comments of the second answer.

Comment: Nice. Remark in passing: Because of wide labels, I needed a further tweak. I ended up setting `widest=100` (a large enough number seemed to work), altogether: `label=Chapter~\arabic*.\quad,align=left,widest=100`.