# The items of the itemize environment protrude into the left margin (scrbook)

Tags: numbering, margins, itemize, scrbook

I use the following idiom in connection with chains of equations. I align the equations using the `align` environment, labeling every equation whose rationale may not be clear to the reader. I follow this chain of equations with an `itemize` environment, in which every `\item` gives a justification to one of the labeled equations. Instead of bullet points, I use the corresponding label. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\begin{theorem}
$2 = 1 + 1$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}
2 &= 2 + 0\label{eq:1}\\
&= 1 + 1\label{eq:2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{itemize}
\item[\eqref{eq:1}] is by Hinkel's lemma, and
\item[\eqref{eq:2}] is by the Fundamental Theorem of Small Integers.
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: itemize's items intrude into the left margin]

As can be seen, the labels used as the "bullet points" of the `itemize` environment protrude into the left margin. How can I correct this, so all the content is rendered between the margins?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398623/134144)? Using the `wide` option of the `enumitem` package might work for your case as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use environment `labeling` which is provided by the KOMA-Script classes.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\begin{theorem}
$2 = 1 + 1$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}
2 &= 2 + 0\label{eq:1}\\
&= 1 + 1\label{eq:2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{labeling}{\eqref{eq:2}}% syntax: \begin{labeling}{<widest label>}
\item[\eqref{eq:1}] is by Hinkel's lemma, and
\item[\eqref{eq:2}] is by the Fundamental Theorem of Small Integers.
\end{labeling}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with more text for the second item:

[image]

If the items are only onelined you can also use:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\begin{theorem}
$2 = 1 + 1$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}
2 &= 2 + 0\label{eq:1}\\
&= 1 + 1\label{eq:2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{labeling}{}
\item[\eqref{eq:1}] is by Hinkel's lemma, and
\item[\eqref{eq:2}] is by the Fundamental Theorem of Small Integers. \blindtext
\end{labeling}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The only difference to the result above is the indent of a possible second line of the items:

[image]

Comment: See my updated answer: you can also use `\begin{labeling}{}`, if a possible second line of an item should not be aligned with the text of its first line.

Answer (score 3):

with use of the `enumitem` package:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\begin{theorem}
$2 = 1 + 1$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}
2 &= 2 + 0\label{eq:1}\\
&= 1 + 1\label{eq:2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{itemize}[wide]
\item[\eqref{eq:1}] is by Hinkel's lemma, and
\item[\eqref{eq:2}] is by the Fundamental Theorem of Small Integers.
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case that do you like get your hands dirty with LaTeX guts, or you do not/cannot use `scrextend`, `enuitem` or other package to format lists, a simple solution is set `\leftmargini` (note the final *i* because is only for the first level of the list) manually or taking into account the label width.

Another approach could use the primitive `list` environment instead of `itemize`, where it is also possible make automatically the equation references. Note that is this case the  modified is `\leftmargin` (without the final "i"). The nice about list is that you can convert in your own simple environment. Examples:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\def\a{is by Hinkel's lemma, and} % one line dummy ext
\def\b{is by the Fundamental Theorem  % two lines dummy ext
of Small Integers. Lore ipsum dolor sit amet and bla bla bla...} 
% \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}  % uncomment to show margins ...
\parindent0pt  % Disclaimer: To lazy to set lenghts in LaTeX mode, sorry. 
               % You should use \setlengths or you will have nightmares.

\newcounter{eq}
\newlength\eqlab
\settowidth\eqlab{\eqref{eq:2}}
\newenvironment{equation-references}{ 
\begin{list}{\eqref{eq:\arabic{eq}}}{\usecounter{eq}
\labelwidth2\eqlab
\labelsep1em 
\leftmargin\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}
}{\end{list}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\begin{theorem} $2 = 1 + 1$ \end{theorem}
\begin{align} 2 &= 2 + 0\label{eq:1}\\&= 1 + 1\label{eq:2} \end{align}

Set \verb|\leftmargini| manually to have label in margin:

{\leftmargini3.3em
\begin{itemize} \item[\eqref{eq:1}] \a \item[\eqref{eq:2}] \b \end{itemize}}

Or with some indentation:

{\leftmargini4em
\begin{itemize} \item[\eqref{eq:1}] \a \item[\eqref{eq:2}] \b \end{itemize}}

With automatic identation according to label width:

{\leftmargini\dimexpr\leftmargini+\eqlab
\begin{itemize} \item[\eqref{eq:1}] \a \item[\eqref{eq:2}] \b \end{itemize}}

Making a simple list autonumbered:

\begin{list}{\eqref{eq:\arabic{eq}}}{\usecounter{eq}}
\item \a \item \b \end{list}

Custom \verb|equation-references| environment with some label indentation:

\begin{equation-references}
\item \a \item \b 
\end{equation-references}

\end{document}
```